Prove that there are orthonormal vector fields $(E_i)$ such that $(\nabla_{E_i}E_j)_p = 0$
Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$. I want to prove that given $p\in M$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and $n$ smooth vector fields $E_1,…,E_n$ defined on $U$ which are orthonormal at each point of $U$ and such that $(\nabla_{E_i}E_j)_p = 0$ for all $i, j$.
Here is my attempt:
Pick a chart $(U, \phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb R^n)$ and pullback the standard coordinate basis of $\mathbb R^n$ to define the coordinate vector fields $(\partial^\phi_i)_p := \phi^*_p (\partial_i) = d(\phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}\partial_i$. Now, use the Gram-Schmidt process to build an orthonormal basis $E_i := \frac{u_i}{\Vert u_i\Vert}$ where
$$u_i := \partial^\phi_i - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \frac {\left\langle\partial^\phi_i, \partial^\phi_j\right\rangle}{\Vert \partial^\phi_i\Vert}\partial^\phi_j.$$
Then we see that the $u_i$ are smooth because the metric and the $\partial^\phi_i$ are smooth. So the $E_i$ are also smooth and orthonormal.
Now, if this is correct, how can I also get $(\nabla_{E_i}E_j)_p = 0$? If I look at the Koszul relations, the three terms like $E_i\langle E_j, E_k\rangle$ vanish but not the other three terms containing the brackets of vector fields. Can I make them vanish at $p$ with some other modification or do I need a different approach?

I would avoid local coordinates completely. Given a local frame field $\{E_i\}$, the connection forms $\omega^j_i$ are defined by
$$\nabla E_i = \sum\omega^j_i\otimes E_j,$$
and let's write the matrix $(\omega^j_i)$ as $\underline\omega$.
If we change frame by $g\colon U\to O(n)$, then in the new frame we have
$$\underline\omega' = g\underline\omega g^{-1} + dg\cdot g^{-1}.$$
Your question is whether we can choose a frame $\{E_i'\}$ so that $\underline\omega'(p)=0$. Set $g(p)=I$ and let $dg(p) = -\underline\omega(p)$. Working, say, on a disk with $p$ at its center, you can easily write down a smooth map $g$ defined on the disk with this property.

I can say then that $g$ is the unique solution of the system of PDEs given by $\frac{\partial g^j{}i}{\partial x^k} = -\omega^{j}{}{ik}$ where $\omega^{j}{}_{ik}$ is defined by $\omega^{j}{}i=\omega^{j}{}{ik}dx^k$ with initial conditions $g^j{}_i =\delta^j{}_i$. Do you mean anything more explicit than that?

All you care about is $\underline\omega'(p)=0$. We certainly cannot make $\underline\omega' = 0$ on an open set unless the manifold is flat. So you do not need any complicated PDE. Just set $g(x)=e^{-\omega(p)(x)}$.

In this case, the $x$ in $g(x)$ on the LHS is a point in a disk in $M$ around $p$. Is $\omega(p)(x)$ the matrix-valued one-form $\omega(p)$ evaluated at the vector $x \in T_pM$ that is identified, via the exponential map, with the point $x\in M$?

I'm writing this working in a local coordinate chart in $\Bbb R^n$, so that $x$ is both a point and a tangent vector at $p=0$.
